# Matching entities with Google AppEngine MapReduce

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-cloud-datastore

I have the following problem: I am using Google Datastore to store two kinds, **Companies** and **Applicants**, both of them come from different data sources so there is no way to link them directly (no common ID).

What I am trying  to achieve is to compare the **name** of the entities of these two kinds (after doing some normalization) and save these as a new entity of type **Match**.

For that I created a MapReduce job on appengine that go through all the applicants (~ 1M entities) and for each entity queries for Companies with the same name (~ 10M entities in total), but the process is painfully slow, I am getting the following throughput:

mapper-calls: 691411 (9.27/sec avg.)
mapper-walltime-ms: 1724026200 (23108.41/sec avg.)

The wall time seems for me a bit too high but I am not sure of what it means, I am running 32 shards and the code is the following:

```
def match_map(applicant):        
    if(applicant.applicant_name_normalised != ""):
        # Check against the companies
        cps = Company.query(Company.name_normalised == applicant.applicant_name_normalised).fetch(projection=[Company.dissolved])
        if(len(cps) > 0):
            is_potential = True
        else:
            return

        m = Match(id=applicant.key.id())
        idList = []

        for c in cps:
            idList.append(c.key)
            if(c.dissolved != True):
                is_potential = False

        m.companies = idList
        m.applicant = applicant.key
        m.is_potential = is_potential
        if(is_potential):
            yield op.db.Put(m)
    idList[:] = []
```

How could I implement this so it runs faster? I am almost to the point of leaving google datastore and doing this on another database or using scripts, I know queries can be expensive but 10 entities/s is just way lower than what I was expecting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of minor tips that could optimize what you do such as:

Instead of fetching all the results, iterate and bail fast if c.dissolved != True (e.g. starts with is_potential = True, set it to True in iterator or return if c.dissolved != True)

However, understanding the data model and what you are trying to achieve may help to come up with a more optimal solution. In general Cloud Datastore is not
designed for cross Kinds joins and maybe Google Cloud SQL would better fit this problem.

Also, data growth expectation would help. As of now loading (10 + 1) millions record (or projected data to save space) into memory and doing an in-memory join
would be simple and feasible but clearly does not scale.

Regarding scale, your current approach may also have an issue if the number of company keys per match would be to large to fit in one entity.

Comment: Hi @ozarov, so we basically try to do a matching between companies that went bankrupt and buyers of some sort of product, this process is meant to run once a month and every time both kinds will contain the same old ones from last month plus a couple thousand new ones and as far as I know they are not going to double anytime soon.

I was thinking indeed in migrating this bit to Redis or some other in memory DB, or possibly MySql to do this matching and then just write the properties of interest back to datastore.

Comment: I will try the suggestions you made tomorrow, the mapper job has been running for over a day now so I really don't want to possibly insert a bug and stop its execution.

Comment: Thanks ozarov, throughput was multiplied by 10! But I just found out I can do the same using BigQuery in a few seconds, so I might use that next time